# Hiding a view based on screen size.

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, size-classes

I tried to search but could not find anything. Or could not ask the right way... =\ 
Anyway I have a simple UIViewController that no mater the screen size things look great. I was asked to add some text to it and this is where the problem arises. On 4.7 and 5.5 screens I have enough room but not on a 4 inch screen. 
Playing with size classes I can not find a way to indicate a 4inch or smaller screen only.
 I want to NOT show the UILabel on a 4 inch screen and DO show it on the other larger two. I'm sure this could be done in code by `[lbl setHidden:YES]` if the screen size is less that x. Is there a way to accomplish this in Interface Builder so I am able to show the boss the layout without having to run it in different simulators or devices? I.E. using the preview editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should play around with Installed property in Attributes Inspector, but you cannot hide for only 4 inch screen, because `wCompact` and `hAny` is for 3.5, 4, 4.7 inch, `wCompact` and `hRegular` is for all iPhone portraits, thus you will hide the label for 3.5, 4, 4.7 inch if you uncheck Installed property for `wCompact` and `hAny`. For such behaviour, you should do by code.

Comment: That's what I figured and kept discovering myself. Just making sure I was not missing a cool little feature tucked away somewhere.  Thank you Sir!